# Are all Local Observables Measured on Gibbs States Analytic as a Function of Temperature Away from Phase Transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, analyticity

Let $\rho(\beta)=e^{-\beta H}/Z$ be the Gibbs state of a quantum Hamiltonian, and $H$ is some local Hamiltonian on $N$ particles, and $Z(\beta)$ is its partition function. Suppose I measure some local observable $A$, $||A||\leq 1$ and want to compute its expectation value:
$$ \langle A\rangle (\beta) = tr(A\rho(\beta)),$$
in an interval $\beta\in [a,b]$.

Assuming that no thermal phase transition takes place $\beta\in [a,b]$, then is it the case that $\langle A\rangle (\beta)$ is an analytic function of $\beta$ for $\beta\in [a,b]$?

My reasoning is as follows: one can always express

$$tr(A\rho(\beta)) =\frac{1}{Z(\beta)} \sum_i  e^{-\beta\lambda_i(H)}  \langle\nu_i|A|\nu_i\rangle, $$
where $|\nu_i\rangle$ are the energy eigenstates of $H$ and $\lambda_i(H)$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

It seems like provided $Z(\beta)$ is analytic for $\beta\in [a,b]$, this expression should be analytic everywhere in that region. Since non-analyticities in the partition function define phase transitions, it should be the case that away from phase transitions we have an analytic expression for the expectation value of the observable. However, it's not totally clear that $\sum_i  e^{-\beta\lambda_i(H)}  \langle\nu_i|A|\nu_i\rangle$ has to be analytic everywhere.

Comment: This is true pretty much by definition: phase transitions are locations where analyticity fails. But you have to be careful, are you interested in the behavior as a function of $\beta$? Your object could be non analytic with respect to some other parameter, even if it's analytic in $\beta$.

Comment: I see. Follow up question: suppose there is a non-analyticity in a parameter y somewhere. Presumably by a similar argument you can say that (assuming no phase transition) that all observables are analytic, but now you're also limited to the region in which there is no phase transition for either \beta or y?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Anyway yes in general phase transition mean that some observable  becomes non analytic. And yes it always depends on the region you are in. Regions of the same phase (where the state can be continuously deformed in different parts of the region) are delimited by phase transitions